# Why do I have traffic to my website that does not show up in my access log file?

Tags: web-hosting

About half of the https traffic coming through my Lighttpd webserver is not being logged.  I know for two reasons.  First, I use a PHP script to count how many times each blog articles is read.  Second, I can see https traffic coming into my Lighttpd server via "sudo iftop -P" and "sudo netstat -atp" that does not show up in my access log, or any other log file.

Comment: I've never seen requests not get logged using Apache.   Maybe switch to Apache and see if it does a better job of logging?

Comment: Is it only certain requests? Such as http vs https?

Comment: It seems to be both http and https requests are not always being logged.  I am using a server with limited processing capability and RAM, so I can't use Apache.